# Why tap gesture recognizer recognizes the taps from the view on its parent view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView and a tap gesture recognizer in it:

```
UIImageView *tabView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(41, 145, 702, 100)];
tabView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive_tab"];
tabView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[tabView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[self.scrollView addSubview:tabView];
```

And I add another view on scrollview:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.activeTab];
```

activeTab is over the inactiveTap. When I tap to activeTap, gesture recognizer fires, whis I dont want to be happened. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and its method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`.
You can check if the touch point is inside a view frame and return `NO` if you don't want the touch to happen on that view.`

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(self.activeTab.frame, touchLocation);
}
```